# How to disaply this .next() element from multiple selectors

Tags: jquery

The code below will hide and show a sub-menu depending on 2 elements using mousenter / mouseleave.

```
var count = 0;
$('.parent-menu, .sub-menu').mouseenter(function(){
    count ++;
    $('.sub-menu').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    count--;
    if(!count) {
        $('.sub-menu').hide();
    }
});
```

The only thing is it displays all submenus on every parent-menu. I know `$(this.next()..etc)` will take the related submenu (as its an adjeacent li with everything in it) but how would i target this when i using multiple selectors?

HTML

```
      <li class="parent-menu">
        <a href="#">Sports</a>
      </li>
       <li class="sub-menu">
          <div class="container menu-background">
             <ul>
                <li class="heading"><a href="#">Running</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Footwear</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Apparel</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>  
        </li>
```

Comment: Can you show your html as well.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?:

```
var count = 0;
$('.parent-menu, .sub-menu').mouseenter(function(){
    count ++;
    $(this).next().show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    count--;
    if(!count) {
        $(this).next().hide();
    }
});
```

`$(this).next().hide();` will select .sub-menu.

Comment: Thanks salivan, Its almost there, except this is taking .parent-menu instead of .sub-menu. How would i select the second selector here? I tried $(this)[1] but this breaks the whole thing.

Comment: @lxm7 your html markup is incorrect, sub-menu must be child of parent menu. This is also how css hover menus work! But if you want to keep this structure than simply use $(this).next().hide()/show()